# Mission Planner: How to create a custom Waypoint Command

Tags: quadcopter, python, ardupilot, mavlink

I am trying to set up a waypoint in Mission Planner that causes the drone to hover, take sensor data from a custom sensor, then either land or continue hovering based off of what the sensor data says.

I haven't found any websites online for how to do this, so does anyone here know how can I make this into a new, custom waypoint in Mission Planner? Do I have to code up my own MAVLink command, or is there another way? By the way, I am using a Pixhawk flight controller with the Ardupilot firmware.